# Any locally compact space is rim compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness, examples-counterexamples

> **Definition**
>
> A topological space $X$ is rim compact if for any $x\in X$ there exist a local basis $\mathcal{B}(x)$ such that for any $B\in\mathcal{B}(x)$ the subspace $\partial B$ is compact.
>
> **Statement**
>
> Any locally compact space is rim compact.

Unfortunately, I can't prove the statement. Anyway, it seems to me that it could be false: however, if we add some hypothesis (e.g hausdorff or tychonoff separability etc...) could it true?

So, could someone help me, please?

Comment: What is your text's definition of "locally compact"?

Comment: BTW the usual name for this property is "rim-compact". In case you're looking for literature. A metric space is rim-compact iff it has a compactification with a zero-dimensional remainder. See the book dimsensions and extensions by Aarts and Nishiura.

Comment: My text claim that a space il locally compact iff  for any $x\in X$ there exist at least a compact nhood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If compact sets are closed (so in a Hausdorff space, e.g.) $\partial B$ is a closed subset of $\overline{B}$ so also compact. So in a Hausdorff space having one compact neighbourhood implies we have a local base of compact neighbourhoods (in the general sense), and so then the space is peripherally compact.

If $X$ is $\Bbb R$ in the included point topology wrt $0$, say, then each point $x$ has a compact neighbourhood $\{x,0\}$ but the boundaries of open sets are mostly not compact.

Comment: Okay, indeed if $X$ is hausdorff separable and too locally compact then for any $x\in X$ there exist a local basis $\mathcal{B}(x)$ such that any $B\in\mathcal{B}(x)$ is compact and so too closed, since $X$ is $T_2$. So we conclude that $\partial B\subseteq B$ for any $B\in\mathcal{B}(x)$ and so $\partial B$ is too compact, since $\partial B$ is closed in $X$ and so even in $B$, right?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro For Hausdorff everything is true, but there are counterexamples in general, as I showed.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro most texts say local basis and mean one of "open" sets, so beware in your write-up.

Comment: Okay, so I have to say that a topologycal space $X$ is peripherally compact if for any $x\in X$ there exist a local OPEN basis $\mathcal{B}(x)$ such that for any $B\in\mathcal{B}(x)$ the subspace $\partial B$ is compact, right?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro that's probably what they mean. Is the statement from the same text as your definition?

Comment: Yes, the statement and the definition are from "Elementos de Topología General" by Fidel Cassarubias Segura and Ángel Tamariz Mascarúa. Unfortunately in other authors (Kuratowski, Engelking, Bourbaki, Willard, etc...) I didn't found any definition of rim-compact space.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro No, it's only studied in some papers and the book "dimensions and extensions" I mentioned. Not a common topic at all.